# Javaを用いてブラウザのHTTPヘッダを取得する方法

Tags: java, google-chrome, http

---

コメントでのご指摘ありがとうございます。曖昧な質問で大変申し訳ありませんでした。
さらに追記を加えようと思いましたが、
質問が見づらいものになってしまったため、質問を編集し、まとめました。

---

・作成したいApp
ブラウザのパケットをキャプチャするアプリ

・やりたいこと
クライアントがブラウザを起動しており、そこにWebページの内容が表示されている。
この状態で、作成したアプリを起動すると、
ブラウザに表示されているWebページが行っている通信データ(HTTPヘッダ、パケット)を取得し表示したい。
そのため、通信が行われるたびに、アプリで表示している情報を更新する必要がある。

・開発主言語
Java

・動作環境
macOS
GoogleChrome

・試したこと
WebDriverを用いて、ブラウザを操作しようとしましたが、
ブラウザの立ち上げが操作はできるものの、通信データを取得する方法がわかりませんでした。

また、コメントにもございますが、同じようなことを行っているアプリがProxyを用いていることが分かったのですが、Proxyについて知識がなく、調べようとしてもなかなか情報がでてきません。

・伺いたいこと
現在開いているWebページのパケットを取得するJavaライブラリは存在するか？
他にJavaでWebページのパケットを取得する方法はあるか？

また、JavaでのHttpProxyについて学べる資料とかあれば、教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: サーバーサイドの話なのかクライアントサイドの話なのか主語がないのでよくわかりません。どのプログラムをどちら（サーバ・クライアント）で動かしたいのか追記していただけると回答がつくかもしれません。

Comment: ブラウザの通信をキャプチャしてなんらかの処理したいのであれば、[jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/)とかでしょうか（使ったことはないので目的に沿うかわかりませんが）。

Comment: 推測するに、ブラウザ(Chrome)が起動していて、そこにWebページの内容が表示されている。その状態で、アプリを起動すると、ブラウザに表示されているWebページの内容(HTML)のヘッダ部分の情報(データ）が表示されるようにしたい。という感じですか？　質問は、何が何をどうするのかが明白に書かれていないので、推測してみるのがやっとです。　質問は、詳細を具体的に書くようにしてください。

Comment: アイデアだけ書くと FiddlerというWindows用のHTTPアナライザのように、HTTP Proxy として動作する Java のアプリを作って ブラウザにはそのProxyのURLを設定すれば、ブラウザとアプリの間の通信を拾うことは出来そうです。どうすれば実現できるか？は生憎私には難しすぎてわかりません…。

Comment: 皆さまコメントありがとうございます。
指摘をうけ、質問を編集しました。
>take88 さんアドバイスありがとうございます。「HTTP Proxy」については、少し調べてきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Proxyを使う方法もありますが、Google Chrome でしたら、remote-debugging-protocolというのを使う方法もあります。
たぶん、それがWebDriverと同じ仕組みと思われます。

https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-1/
これは、WebSocketを使ってChromeに接続するのですが、ChromeでのDevToolでとれる情報と同様の情報がとれます。

基本的には、Chromeをremote-debug付きで起動したあとに、WebSocketでそこに接続すれば取得できます。
Macでのremote-debugを有効にしたChromeの起動方法は以下にあるので、参考にしてください。
http://www.coltware.com/2016/06/13/console_log_to_file/